# Why isn't 'require' working?

Tags: solidity, remix, string, require

In the create function, I need the `_title` to be required and the `_description` to be optional. But when calling create without `_title` & with `_description`, it executes without any errors, but the `_description` gets assigned to the title in the struct.

Why isn't require working here? I'm using Remix Web.

**Input**

_title:
_description:Testing

**`search(0)` output**

0:string:Testing
1:string:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {    

struct Object {
        uint256 id;
        string title;
        string description;        
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Object) objects;
    uint256 count;

    function create(string memory _title, string memory _description) public {
        require(bytes(_title).length > 0, "title must be set");
        
        objects[count] = Object(count, _title, _description);
        count++;
    }

    function search(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory, string memory){
        return (objects[_id].title, objects[_id].description);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Remix IDE, you should pass into _title parameter the following value: `""` (empty quotes) for indicating it that specific parameter doesn't have any values.
If you'll try in this way, you should see the error in `require()` statement.